# Kill a nohup mpi process

Tags: mpi, kill, nohup

I have started a program in parallel using the command:

```
    nohup mpirun -7 mylongprogram.py &
```

I now want to terminate the program. When I want to kill the process by the command:

```
    kill -9 <PID>
```

I see that another process with a different PID is started. How do I kill the entire mpi program and prevent nohup from doing this?

Comment: Questions about usage of general Unix tools like `nohup` should be asked on the [Super User site](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: "prevent nohup from doing this". From doing what ?

Answer (score 2):

The command I usually do this is to use:

```
killall -u [USER]
```

Comment: Or, if you feel daring, `kill -15 -1` as your non-root mpi-user (which logs you out, too).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of forcing the program to shut down from the outside, I'd try triggering a clean exit from inside. For example, create a file somewhere that the program periodically checks if it exists, and shuts itself down if it does (related reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433697/terminating-all-processes-with-mpi).

Answer (score 1):

`killall mpirun`

or more specifically for your case :

`ps -ef | grep mpirun | grep mylongprogram | awk '{print $2}' | while read p; do kill -9 $p ; done`